# Choosing the managerial or specialist path - does that really matter if you're senior in IT?

Tags: career-development

I'm wondering if me choosing the managerial or specialist path really matters.

I'm at the senior manager level (I mean the career level, not a function). I want my next job to be on the director level. I have the impression that the higher you go the less technicalities you do anyway, you mostly oversee others doing technical tasks but your understanding of these technicalities matters to some degree, no matter if you're a manager or an expert.

Even if you're an expert, if you're not doing hands-on technical development you are forgetting things and not up-to-date with the newest developments, so you become less technical with time.

On the other hand, no matter if you're an expert or a manager, the meaning of networking with other leads, alignments, generally the time spent in meetings increases as you progress.

And I do have the impression that most such jobs recruiters contact me about go into the direction of managing teams and projects: sometimes in a more technical way (the specialist path), sometimes in a slightly less technical way (managerial path). The companies I mean are companies in industries such as pharma, retail and others and in consulting, **not** software houses. And yet, I am constantly asked if I see myself as an expert or manager.

Could you offer me a quick reality check if my impressions described above are correct?

Answer (score 3):

Management and expert growth tracks differ the most in the internal motivators that drive them.

Do you want to be the smartest, most knowledgeable, most successful person on your team?
Yes: High-level IC
No: Manager

Do you want to deal with the personal problems of everyone on your team?
Do you prefer to facilitate the discussion, rather than lead it and prove you're right?
Do you like being personally responsible for the actions and results of others on your team?
No: IC
Yes: Manager

As a manager, in good companies, your job is to help the people on your team grow, communicate, and deliver their best results. As a *high-level* IC, your job is to make the high-impact decisions, or to summarize the options down to simple pros-and-cons that will drive the decision-making.

There is some overlap, but it's a very big difference in motivation. If you're really torn between the two, it's a good idea to spend a few sessions with your advisor of choice on finding what brings you enjoyment and pleasure, particularly when you're not getting paid for it, then match it with the right job.